# Sign in via Telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, telegram-api

I've written a script for my friend, which uses Telethon. There I sign in with the following line^

```
with TelegramClient('test', API_ID, API_HASH) as client:
```

Well, it actually works with my account and another one, that is not mine. However, my buddy can't pass the auth. He doesn't receive verification code, no matter which device or which account he uses.

Have anyone had such an experience? What it can be stemmed from?

EDITED: Linking your account with an email might be of help. I now receive this codes in such a way.

Comment: Log in using telegram desktop or from a mobile phone, then log in with telethon again

Comment: Tried. Doesn't work

Comment: The otp will go in telegram. Check if you have a message from an account named Telegram in there.

Comment: @СергейКох it's not that it's question isn't well formulated, which isn't the case anyway. The answer is not so simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely experiencing the same as was reported in [Telethon's issues - Telegram has stopped sending SMS code](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/3835). Many users have reported this before (linked issues, and probably some more I missed).

As underwhelming as the answer is, it's probably some server-side check, depending on phone numbers or even location, which Telethon cannot do anything to "fix" it. As far as I'm aware there's no known workaround (for better of worse, as spammers are also, at least, slowed down by this).

Comment: Someone fixed it, in one of the issues related to the one linked by you. But he did to set up a two factor authentification to receive the code via email.

Comment: Got you. Well, I'll probably try deleting-creating friend's account. Maybe this will work. Thanks, for your response)

Comment: @MarcelAlexandru, your comment really helped. Thank you